# OpenVPN service cannot start

Tags: openvpn, fedora, systemd

I configure OpenVPN on my VPS (Fedora 23) and I have an issue with starting it as systemd service.
From command line (`openvpn server.conf`) all works fine, but when I try start it via systemd it fails.

`systemctl status openvpn@server.service` show me this:

```
● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On myvps/tcp
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-12-10 06:04:07 UTC; 13min ago
Main PID: 500 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps openvpn[500]: ROUTE: default_gateway=UNDEF
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps openvpn[500]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps openvpn[500]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps openvpn[500]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps openvpn[500]: /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps openvpn[500]: Linux ip link set failed: could not execute external program
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps openvpn[500]: Exiting due to fatal error
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 10 06:04:07 myvps systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I see that OpenVPN can't execute `ip` command, but I don't see why. When I start OpenVPN manually I don't get this error.

The unpriv-ip script is set up as described in [official howto](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#security).

The OpenVPN service start after `network.target` and wanted by `multi-user.target`, if it matters.

Can someone explain me what is the problem?

Thank you.

**UPD** (for Anubioz)

```
# dnf install iproute
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:27:44 ago on Thu Dec 10 05:52:27 2015.
Package iproute-4.1.1-3.fc23.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

# ls -l /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 27 Dec 10 01:23 /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip
```

**UPD2** (for Anubioz)

```
# dnf install iputils
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:42:05 ago on Thu Dec 10 05:52:27 2015.
Package iputils-20140519-7.fc23.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that `/usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip` script has *execute* permissions (+x chmod flag)

You can set it with the following command

`chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip`

2. Check that your openvpn config has the `script-security 2` line to allow execution of external scripts.
3. Make sure you got `iproute` package installed and the `ip` command availible on your system.

You can install it with:

`yum install iproute iputils`

4. Try adding `sleep 5` to the top of your `/usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip` script to make sure it won't be executed before tun0 device is availible.

Comment: Of course, the script has execute permissions and `iproute` is installed. Otherwise I think OpenVPN would fails even I start it manually.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I edited the answer

Comment: No, both packages are already installed.

Comment: And `ip` commad is availible, of course.

Comment: Do you have `script-security 2` in your config? Does the `/usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500` work when run from command line as a opevpn user? Can you paste the contents somewhere?

Comment: Result is one line: `Cannot find device "tun0"`.

Comment: Try adding sleep 5 to the top of the script to see if it helps. (In case the tun0 is not fully initialized when script is started)

Comment: Hmm. You're right, it works. But why this workaround are not necessary when I start OpenVPN manually?

Comment: This seems to be systemd related check [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185352) and [this](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2012-January/160917.html)

Comment: I thought that OpenVPN create `tun0` device itself, doesn't it?

Comment: No, unless you run the `openvpn --mktun --dev tun0` to create persistent tun0 device, it will be dynamically created and deleted every time you start/stop openvpn.

Comment: I try Poettering's advice `Wants=dev-tun0.device; After=dev-tun0.device` as more clean solution. Unfortunately, it do not fix the problem. I think root of the problem is in something else. How can OpenVPN service waits for the `tun` device if OpenVPN dynamically create it?

Comment: Try adding `route-delay 5` to your openvpn config file if you want a ['cleaner' solution](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage) (that does exactly the same as `sleep 5` :). In my experience adding some occasional `sleep 1` helps greatly for fixing systemd-related scripts, though. So I suggest you don't underestimate this simple solution...